# nginx internet explorer failed connection

Tags: nginx, internet-explorer

I have a simple website with a login form using Websockets .Although it works fine with Firefox and Chrome, no connection is established and thus no login using IE 10 or 11. I used Fiddler and noticed that the result in successful connections is 101(that is in Chrome and Firefox),while in IE it is 200. Furthermore,the following message :

```
SCRIPT12008: WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 200, OK
```

appears in IE console.

These are the IE , Chrome and FF headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: test.server.com
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: el,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Host: test.server.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://test.kolibri.beckipc.io/
Accept-Language: el,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test.server.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Somehow nginx does not respond properly when IE is used.Any ideas?

Comment: what do you see in the access and error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Two browser engines out of three tested work just fine. IE header is the only one with Accept-Language communications header limited to de-DE. Are you by any chance serving one version, and IE decides it doesn't want it? After all, IE does not report a problem, but a status code "200 OK".

Let me rephrase the above:

1. In the web page that includes your form, define the language as de-DE
2. Purge the cache in IE
3. Load the new form created in step 1 in IE.

That should do it. (If this does not work, try loading your original form in IE after changing your language preference in that browser from de-DE to en-US and see what happens.) And one other thing: make sure you have all most recent updates from Microsoft. Microsoft is actually known to fix bugs regularly. Good luck:-)